# How do I fix a error on a failed module build for Virtualbox?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, virtualbox

world. 
I'm trying to upgrade my system but I get the error:

`Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.2.0-37-generic (i686)`

```
Deleting module version: 4.1.12
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-4.1.12 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.2.0-37-generic
Building initial module for 3.2.0-37-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.2.0-37-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to upgrade? Ubuntu? Upgrading the entire OS to 12.10 or just upgrading the packages on your current Ubuntu? Or are you trying to upgrade only VirtualBox? etc

Comment: I just want to update the system. that error I get it since I made the last update.

Comment: So this is as a result of `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Did you look into `/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/make.log` like the error message suggested? You can edit your question to post it or (if it is too big) use http://pastebin.ubuntu.com and put the link into your question.

Comment: LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
Unable to exec gcc.real: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic'

Answer (score 3):

1.) `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox`

2.) reboot

3.) `sudo ln -si /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 /usr/bin/gcc`

4.) reboot

4.) `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`

5.) optional reboot. :)

that all kids..!!

Comment: Must it be 4.6? On my machine /usr/bin/gcc is already symlinked to gcc-4.7

Answer (score 1):

You can check the error in the log, in most case it used a gcc/g++ option that not supported in your current version.

You can install a newer version of gcc and g++, and manage with update-alternatives. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu

After that reinstall virtualbox-dkms.

```
 sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox-dkms
```